# Sending a simple message from user to user in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, message

I am trying to create a simple form that allows users to send messages to each other in Django. My model looks like this:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='messages_to')
    sender = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='messages_from')
    message = models.TextField(blank=True)
    unread = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

And my form looks like this:

```
class MessageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ('message',)
```

I would like to display the form on the recipients profile page. I think I need to include the senders id in the url for django to know where the message is coming from, so I link to the recipients page with this url:

```
path('profile/<int:user_id>/<int:sender_id>', ProfileDetailView.as_view(), name='profile_detail')
```

Finally here is my view which renders the users profile page and the form to send the message:

```
class ProfileDetailView(FormMixin, DetailView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'users/detail.html'
    form_class = MessageForm

    def get_object(self):
        profile = Profile.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['user_id'])
        return profile

    def form_valid(self, form):
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.user = Profile.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['user_id'])
        instance.sender = Profile.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['sender_id'])
        instance.save()
        return super(ProfileDetailView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('/')
```

Currently the page and form are rendering correctly however when I type a message into the form and click send the page only refreshes and turns blank. No message object is recorded in django-admin, and I do not receive any errors. Can anyone please explain why my data is not being passed to the form? Or is there another error here?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change DetailView to CreateView and it works now

Comment: hello please can you help me, I am facing same problem